# Multi tenant application in grails with shared DB Separate schema can any one provide any demo app or any good reference for that

Tags: postgresql, grails, multi-tenant

I have to make a web application multi-tenant enabled using Shared database separate schema approach. Application is built using Grails and PostgreSQL .

I need to have one single app server using a shared database with multiple schema, each schema per client.

What is the best implementation approach to achieve this? - What needs to be done at the middle tier(app-server) level? - Do I need to have multiple host headers each per client? - How can I connect to the correct schema dynamically based on the client who is accessing the application?

Any links or pointers would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work about what you tried? SO isn't the place for recommendations, or pointers to outside resources. Also, you may want to limit your question to one question at a time.

Comment: i have tried multi tenancy with Shared database and tables, but i' m  not getting how to initiate with separate schema .

Comment: hey can you share implementation steps